# Hardwired ethernet not working but wireless is

Tags: wireless, ethernet

I have 2 ethernet cards (built into my motherboard) and 1 wireless card (assigned via dhcp  as 192.168.1.67 by my ATT dsl modem/router) on my linux box.  Wireless works fine.  I tried using Network manager to configure eth1 but when I entered the desired IP address and Network Mask (255.255.255.0) then clicked save, the setting wouldn't take.  If I immediately typed "ifconfig" I would get this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4b:15:45:77  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4b:15:45:78  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:501 errors:341 dropped:18 overruns:340 frame:1
      TX packets:457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:57297 (57.2 KB)  TX bytes:45203 (45.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:105359 (105.3 KB)  TX bytes:105359 (105.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:36:46:12  
      inet addr:192.168.1.67  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:caff:fe36:4612/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:14142088 (14.1 MB)  TX bytes:1208084 (1.2 MB)
```

It is obvious that eth1 was not configured even though I just configured it using the network manager tool.  It's as if I didn't do anything.  So I searched the web looking for something... something to enlighten me.  I eventually found someone with a somewhat similar problem.  So  I started to follow what they did and here is some of what I did.

### Dump of /etc/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:04:4B:15:45:77,

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

---

Notice the "managed = true." I changed that.  It previously said, "managed = false."

I then went into the /etc/network/interfaces file and added the text starting at "# The primary hard-wired network interface"

/ect/networks/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

  # The loopback interface
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  # The primary hard-wired network interface
  iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.4
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Then i save that and tried restarting network services. Nothing changed so after changing that file I typed:

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.4 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

I typed ifconfig and I could see the card was configured with the network address I wanted.  Things started to look promising but of course I wouldn't be typing this if I got it working.

So I tried pinging the 192.168.1.4 address from another computer (192.168.1.6) on the same wired network, but If I tried the reverse by pinging that other computer(192.168.1.6)  from 192.168.1.4 it would just hang there forever displaying:

```
frequencydrive@Hacker:~$ ping 192.168.1.6
PING 192.168.1.6 (192.168.1.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

It would just hang there not responding to the ping.  I also noticed that I could no longer surf the internet.  If I tried going to google immediately after using the "ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.4..." command shown above I could not get anywhere using Firefox.  It seemed to lose it's route to the default gateway? If I brought down the interface by typing:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 down
```

I could immediately surf the web.

What the heck is causing all this?  I just want a wired network and a wireless network all on the same 192.168.1.x address space.

Some of the things I did I got from this thread:

[Trying to configure eth0 and eth1 but Failed to bring up eth1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304898/trying-to-configure-eth0-and-eth1-but-failed-to-bring-up-eth1)

I've been working on this problem for days.  It's so frustrating.  Why does networking have to be so hard with Linux?

Thanks for any help.