# network configuration with two NICs

Tags: networking

this is my network design.

i have two interfaces in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop. one is eth0 and other is eth1. I have two routers for that.

DSL wire is coming to router1 than wire from router1 coming to eth0 interface. So i'd be able to connect to internet but i m not, until i run the "dhclient" command.
then eth0 is setup to send traffic to eth1 and a wire from eth1 is connected to router2. Now i am connecting my phone with wifi to that router2 it connects but i am unable to access the internet.

my IP forwarding is OK !
n
I want to access internet plus the routing between two NICs, so that i can access internet from router2 also !!!

And it was working properly a week ago.

Please help to properly configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bridge the two networks
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

or route all traffic through eth0
i think this is a proper example: [Trying to configure eth0 and eth1 but Failed to bring up eth1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304898/trying-to-configure-eth0-and-eth1-but-failed-to-bring-up-eth1)

Comment: it does not help....Please suggest some other fix ! @Frank

Comment: what does  'ip route show' show?

Comment: Sorry for delay as the system is at workplace !

The ip route shows :

default via 192.168.x.x dev eth0...............
10.10.xx.x/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.xx.xx..........
192.168.x.x/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.x.x